How can I split a boost::multiprecision::int128_t into a hi and lo int64_t portions?
Packing and Unpacking 128-bit Integers using Boost Multiprecision
I'm compressing two 64-bit integers, i0 and i1, into a single 128-bit integer using the formula i = i0 * 2^64 + i1. The resulting multi-precision integer will undergo various arithmetic operations. However, I'm struggling to define the reverse operation to extract the original i0 and i1 values from the multi-precision integer.
The goal is to create the function unpack that is the inverse of the function pack is defined by
using int128_t = boost::multiprecision::int128_t;
// This packing is the definition of the desired multi-precision integer.
// Its definition is not negotiable.
auto pack = [](const std::array<int64_t, 2>& value) {
    return (((static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64) * value[0]) + value[1]);
};

The following code fails to properly invert the packing with boost::multiprecision::int128_t :
C++
auto unpack = [](const int128_t& value) {
    const auto lo = static_cast<int64_t>(value % (static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64));
    return std::array<int64_t, 2>{
        static_cast<int64_t>((value - lo) / (static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64)),
        lo
    };
};

The unpacking function doesn't work as expected. However, the same code works fine when using __int128 (a two's complement implementation). Does anyone know how to implement the unpack function to work correctly with Boost Multiprecision?
A version of the code that tests both boost's and native's int128 implementations is available by following the link:
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include "boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp"

#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"


template <typename OStream> OStream& operator<< (OStream& stream, const std::array<int64_t, 2>& value)
{
    stream << "{ " << value[0] << ", " << value[1] << " }";
    
    return stream;
}

template <typename OStream> OStream& operator<< (OStream& stream, __int128 value)
{
    if (value == 0) {
        stream << "0";
        return stream;
    }

    std::string result;
    const auto is_negative = (value < 0);

    if (is_negative) 
        value = -value;

    while (value > 0) {
        result = char('0' + (value % 10)) + result;
        value /= 10;
    }

    if (is_negative)
        result = "-" + result;

    stream << result;

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
#define USE_INT128
#ifdef USE_INT128
    using int128_t = __int128;
    constexpr auto ExtendedType = " Extended type __int128";
#else
    using int128_t = boost::multiprecision::int128_t;
    constexpr auto ExtendedType = " Extended type boost::multiprecision::int128_t";
#endif

    auto pack = [](const std::array<int64_t, 2>& value) {
        return (((static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64) * value[0]) + value[1]);
    };
    
    auto unpack = [](const int128_t& value) {
        const auto lo = static_cast<int64_t>(value % (static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64));
        return std::array<int64_t, 2>{
            static_cast<int64_t>((value - lo) / (static_cast<int128_t>(1) << 64)),
            lo
        };
    };

    for (auto hiLo : { 
        std::array<int64_t, 2> { static_cast<int64_t> (-2), (static_cast<int64_t> (1) << 63) },
        std::array<int64_t, 2> { static_cast<int64_t> (-1), 1 },
        std::array<int64_t, 2> { 1, -10 }, 
        std::array<int64_t, 2> { 1, (static_cast<int64_t> (1) << 63) } 
        })
    {
        std::cout << "====================================" << ExtendedType << std::endl;
        std::cout << "hiLo    = " << hiLo << std::endl;
        const auto extended = pack (hiLo);
        const auto backToHiLo = unpack (extended);

        std::cout << "extended = " << extended << std::endl;
        if (hiLo != backToHiLo)
         std::cout << "Failed to unpack - to_HiLo (to_ExtendedInteger (" << hiLo << ")) = " << backToHiLo << std::endl;
        std::cout << "eExtended   = " << pack (backToHiLo) << std::endl << std::endl;
     }

    return 0;
}


The problem is from sign extension. Bit manipulation becomes a lot easier if you make the inert parts uint64_t. Is there a reason you can't do that?
Here's a demo, updated for the comments. We generalize Tuple (which can be array<int64_t, 2>, array<uint64_t, 2>, tuple<int64_t, uint64_t> etc.) as well as T (which can be Boost's or the compiler builtin 128 bit signed integer type).
template <typename Tuple> Tuple make(auto hi, auto lo) {
    return Tuple{
        std::tuple_element_t<0, Tuple>(hi),
        std::tuple_element_t<1, Tuple>(lo),
    };
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple> T single_test(Tuple const& hiLo) {
    auto pack = [](Tuple const& v) {
        static_assert(sizeof(v) == 2 * sizeof(int64_t));
        auto& [hi, lo] = v;
        return (T(static_cast<int64_t>(hi)) << 64) + static_cast<uint64_t>(lo);
    };
    auto unpack = [](T const& v) -> Tuple {
        static constexpr T scale64 = T(1) << 64;
        return make<Tuple>(                          //
            static_cast<int64_t>(v >> 64),           //
            static_cast<uint64_t>(v & (scale64 - 1)) //
        );
    };

    auto const extended  = pack(hiLo);
    auto const roundtrip = unpack(extended);

    if (hiLo != roundtrip)
        fmt::print("\n\n ****Failed*** to unpack {} - to_HiLo (to_ExtendedInteger ({})) = {}\n\n", //
                   Name<T>, hiLo, roundtrip);
    // fmt::print("eExtended   = {0}\n\n", pack(roundtrip));
    return extended;
}

template<typename Tuple> void run_tests() {
    fmt::print("\n==== {} ====\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    for (auto hiLo : {
             make<Tuple>(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, 0x8000000000000000),
             make<Tuple>(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF, 1),
             make<Tuple>(1, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF6),
             make<Tuple>(1, 0x8000000000000000),
         }) {
        // fmt::print("hiLo      = {}\n", hiLo);
        auto a     = single_test<__int128_t>(hiLo);
        auto b     = single_test<boost::multiprecision::int128_t>(hiLo);
        auto match = (a == b);
        fmt::print("Matching: {} ({} == {})\n", match, a, b);
        assert(match);
    }
}

int main() {
    run_tests<std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t>>();
    run_tests<std::tuple<uint64_t, int64_t>>();
    run_tests<std::tuple<int64_t, uint64_t>>();
    run_tests<std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t>>();
    run_tests<std::array<uint64_t, 2>>();
    run_tests<std::array<int64_t, 2>>();
}

Live On Coliru
Printing
==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::tuple<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::tuple<long unsigned int, long int>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::tuple<long int, long unsigned int>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::tuple<long int, long int>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::array<long unsigned int, 2>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

==== void run_tests() [with Tuple = std::array<long int, 2>] ====
Matching: true (-27670116110564327424 == -27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (36893488147419103222 == 36893488147419103222)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)

BONUS
Beefed up with systematic edge-cases construction and roundtrip verification in all possible combination, as well as a million uniformly random HiLo samples for each run:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <fmt/ostream.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <fmt/std.h>
#include <random>

static constexpr size_t NUM_RANDOM_SAMPLES = 1'000'000;

template <> struct fmt::formatter<boost::multiprecision::int128_t> : fmt::ostream_formatter {};
#define ABORT_ASSERT(cond)                                                                                   \
    do {                                                                                                     \
        if (!(cond)) {                                                                                       \
            fmt::print("Assertion failed: {} in {}:{}\n", #cond, __FILE__, __LINE__);                        \
            ::exit(1);                                                                                       \
        }                                                                                                    \
    } while (false)

template <typename Tuple> Tuple make(auto hi, auto lo) {
    return Tuple{
        std::tuple_element_t<0, Tuple>(hi),
        std::tuple_element_t<1, Tuple>(lo),
    };
};

template <typename T, typename Tuple> struct Impl { // Helpers grouping template parameters
    static constexpr std::string_view Name() { return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }

    static auto pack(Tuple const& v) {
        static_assert(sizeof(v) == 2 * sizeof(int64_t));
        auto& [hi, lo] = v;
        return (T(static_cast<int64_t>(hi)) << 64) + static_cast<uint64_t>(lo);
    };
    static Tuple unpack(T const& v) {
        static constexpr T scale64 = T(1) << 64;
        return make<Tuple>(                          //
            static_cast<int64_t>(v >> 64),           //
            static_cast<uint64_t>(v & (scale64 - 1)) //
        );
    };
    static T run_single_test(Tuple const& hiLo) {
        auto const extended  = pack(hiLo);
        auto const roundtrip = unpack(extended);

        if (hiLo != roundtrip)
            fmt::print("\n\n ****Failed*** to unpack {} - to_HiLo (to_ExtendedInteger ({})) = {}\n\n", //
                       Name(), hiLo, roundtrip);
        else
            ABORT_ASSERT(hiLo == roundtrip);

        ABORT_ASSERT(pack(roundtrip) == extended);
        ABORT_ASSERT(unpack(pack(roundtrip)) == roundtrip); // etc... just driving the point home

        return extended;
    }
};

template <typename Tuple> void run_batch_tests(bool verbose, std::vector<Tuple> const& testCases) {
    using GCC   = Impl<__int128_t, Tuple>;
    using Boost = Impl<boost::multiprecision::int128_t, Tuple>;

    for (auto hiLo : testCases) {
        // fmt::print("hiLo      = {}\n", hiLo);
        auto a     = GCC::run_single_test(hiLo);
        auto b     = Boost::run_single_test(hiLo);
        auto match = (a == b);
        if (verbose)
            fmt::print("Matching: {} ({} == {})\n", match, a, b);
        ABORT_ASSERT(match);
    }
}

template <typename Tuple> auto generateRandomSamples(size_t seed, unsigned howMany) {
    auto gen = bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<uint64_t>{}, std::mt19937_64(seed));

    std::vector<Tuple> result;
    generate_n(back_inserter(result), howMany, [&] { return make<Tuple>(gen(), gen()); });
    return result;
}

template <typename Tuple> void driver(size_t seed) {
    enum : bool { quiet, verbose };
    run_batch_tests<Tuple>(quiet, generateRandomSamples<Tuple>(seed, NUM_RANDOM_SAMPLES));

    fmt::print("\n==== {} ====\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    fmt::print("{:L} uniform random samples passed (seed: {})\n", NUM_RANDOM_SAMPLES, seed);

    using Hi    = std::tuple_element_t<0, Tuple>;
    using Lo    = std::tuple_element_t<1, Tuple>;
    using HiLim = std::numeric_limits<Hi>;
    using LoLim = std::numeric_limits<Lo>;

    std::vector<Tuple> edgeCases;
    for (Hi hi : {Hi{}, Hi{+1}, static_cast<Hi>(-1), //
                  HiLim::min(), HiLim::max(),        //
                  Hi(LoLim::min()), Hi(LoLim::max())})
        for (Lo lo : {Lo{}, Lo{+1}, static_cast<Lo>(-1), //
                      LoLim::min(), LoLim::max(),        //
                      Lo(HiLim::min()), Lo(HiLim::max())})
            edgeCases.push_back(Tuple{hi, lo});

    std::ranges::sort(edgeCases);
    edgeCases.erase(std::unique(edgeCases.begin(), edgeCases.end()), edgeCases.end());

    run_batch_tests<Tuple>(verbose, edgeCases);
}

int main() {
    size_t const seed = std::random_device{}();
    fmt::print("Seed: {}\n", seed);
    driver<std::tuple<uint64_t, uint64_t>>(seed);
    driver<std::tuple<uint64_t, int64_t>>(seed);
    driver<std::tuple<int64_t, uint64_t>>(seed);
    driver<std::tuple<int64_t, int64_t>>(seed);
    driver<std::array<uint64_t, 2>>(seed);
    driver<std::array<int64_t, 2>>(seed);
}

Printing

Seed: 675096274

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::tuple<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::tuple<long unsigned int, long int>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (9223372036854775808 == 9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (27670116110564327423 == 27670116110564327423)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == 170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554112 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554112)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329919 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329919)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == -170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105728 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105728)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329921 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329921)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775809 == -9223372036854775809)

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::tuple<long int, long unsigned int>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105728 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105728)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329921 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329921)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == -170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775809 == -9223372036854775809)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807)
Matching: true (9223372036854775808 == 9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (27670116110564327423 == 27670116110564327423)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554112 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554112)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329919 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329919)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == 170141183460469231731687303715884105727)

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::tuple<long int, long int>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == -170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105728 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105728)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329921 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329921)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775809 == -9223372036854775809)
Matching: true (9223372036854775808 == 9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (27670116110564327423 == 27670116110564327423)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == 170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554112 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554112)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329919 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329919)

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::array<long unsigned int, 2>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)

==== void driver(size_t) [with Tuple = std::array<long int, 2>; size_t = long unsigned int] ====
1000000 uniform random samples passed (seed: 675096274)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == -170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105728 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105728)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == -170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (-170141183460469231722463931679029329921 == -170141183460469231722463931679029329921)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775808 == -9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (-1 == -1)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551616 == -18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (-18446744073709551615 == -18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (-9223372036854775809 == -9223372036854775809)
Matching: true (9223372036854775808 == 9223372036854775808)
Matching: true (18446744073709551615 == 18446744073709551615)
Matching: true (0 == 0)
Matching: true (1 == 1)
Matching: true (9223372036854775807 == 9223372036854775807)
Matching: true (27670116110564327424 == 27670116110564327424)
Matching: true (36893488147419103231 == 36893488147419103231)
Matching: true (18446744073709551616 == 18446744073709551616)
Matching: true (18446744073709551617 == 18446744073709551617)
Matching: true (27670116110564327423 == 27670116110564327423)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329920 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329920)
Matching: true (170141183460469231731687303715884105727 == 170141183460469231731687303715884105727)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554112 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554112)
Matching: true (170141183460469231713240559642174554113 == 170141183460469231713240559642174554113)
Matching: true (170141183460469231722463931679029329919 == 170141183460469231722463931679029329919)


Hi @sehe, Thank you for your detailed explanation! The code indeed packs and unpacks the integers almost as desired. However, I still need to resolve one issue. When packing a pair of uint64_t values, the resulting boost::multiprecision::cpp_int has a different value than when packing a pair of int64_t values. This discrepancy affects the results of integer divisions represented by the pair of high and low values. For example, see this demonstration:https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/607e63d197a0e0c1

Ah. Yeah. I forgot that the target type is signed. Avoid the sign extension issues alltogether: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa43f74c3b47f4be. Here's the answer code refactored, which also shows how to make it so that the type of Tuple really doesn't matter anymore:  https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3808c193d32ccd57

Updated the answer to reflect the better demonstration.

thank you again for the code. But there is still a problem. The to signed integers i0, and i1 are input that define an integer by the formula i = i0 * 2^64 + i1. This is a constrain. This integer will be used to multiply, divide, add, etc. The final integer, j needs to be unpack. Thus, we can play all the games we want with unpacking but the packing is not negotiable. Your packing produces a different value that can't be used. Here's the code that illustrates the issue. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/950dd0b3d2615f90

I updated the question to define clearly what the pack function should do.

Mmm? You're just comparing the fixed pack function with the one that is buggy. Of course they don't match. My pack/unpack already satisfies all the requirements ("The goal is to ensure that the packing and unpacking operations are inverses of each other"): https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/800fbce4f8e2961f I've run this for an hour every .5 seconds, so roughly 7.2 billion uniform random samples through every combination of int128 implementation AND possible Tuple representation. I'd say it's pretty solid.

I stated that the packing function is defined by
$pack = a[0] * 2^62 + a[1]$
The value of the output of packing function can't be changed. Your packing function doesn't generate that output.
I might have found the answer to the problem. I will post it in a bit. Feel free to comment on it. Thank you for trying, and not giving up. Seems to me that you are hooked on creating a packing/unpacking function and not on creating an unpacking function for the pack defined above.

You did, in fact, not state that some how the packing function was somehow a given. Besides, the only correct/useful semantics for a signed int128_t are as shown (because it maintains two's complement). Again, if you desire something else, you would go with uint128_t. Of course, if you need the broken semantics for some legacy reason, you can do that. I think my answer shows you ALL of the different ways to control sign extension where you need to. It's hardly my fault that the question wasn't clear, the test cases didn't cover the requirements and you kept moving the goalposts.

the problem takes signed integers, the pack is fixed, it has a very specific meaning, and whether it's legacy or not, I cannot do what I wish to ensure that the packing and unpacking are inverses of each other. Please, read the question again. I did notice that my original statement lack that condition on the pack, and proceeded to edit it. In addition, I did point out a couple of comments ago that the pack function is fixed.
Regardless, I did appreciate your style of programming. I actually learned a couple of neat tricks such as std::generate_n. I will post the answer shortly.

Let's just agree to disagree. Usually when the code includes tests, those are the requirements. The Tuple type can be fixed, and I adapted my answer to support your choice (among anything else). We all learned in this exchange. I hope it includes thinking about how to best present a problem. Cheers.

I posted my solution. Feel free to comment or improve it now that you understand better the requirements. Thanks again for your time.

I found an implementation of the function to unpack a boost::multiprecision::int128_t into a std::array<int64_t, 2>, but I'm not confident about its robustness across all possible cases.
After studying the Boost multi-precision code and experimenting, I came up with:
inline std::array<int64_t, 2> unpack_int128_t (const boost::multiprecision::int128_t& value) 
{
    constexpr auto TwoPowerNBits = boost::multiprecision::int128_t (1) << 64;
    const auto lo = (value % TwoPowerNBits);
    const auto hi = (value - static_cast<int64_t> (lo)) / TwoPowerNBits;
    
    if (lo != (static_cast<int64_t> (lo)))
    {
        return ((lo > 0) ?
            std::array { static_cast<int64_t>(hi + 1), static_cast<int64_t> (lo - TwoPowerNBits) } :
            std::array { static_cast<int64_t>(hi - 1), static_cast<int64_t> (lo + TwoPowerNBits) });
    }

    return std::array { static_cast<int64_t>(hi), static_cast<int64_t> (lo) };
}

Concerns and Suggestions
While this function works for my test cases (available on Coliru), I'm not confident in its generality. It would be beneficial if the Boost library provided a function to split a multi-precision object into n integers satisfying:
Here is the rendered mathematical expression:

This function could work similarly to convert_to<...>, returning a vector with the minimal set of integers. The function could be named unpack_to_vector that would take, for example, a boost::multiprecision::int128_t as input, returning a std::vector<int64_t>.
std::vector<int64_t> unpack_to_vector(const boost::multiprecision::int128_t& value);

In general, the function would depend on the size of the multi-precision integer. This would provide a more robust and general solution for unpacking multi-precision integers given that boost's implementation does not adhere to the most common two's complement implementation used by our compilers.

Just started reading the tests (they should probably be in the post). Here's some style review. Incidentally >40 LoC shorter. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1990f60d4708a5b9 I'm a bit miffed. You, again ONLY check roundtripping. So you add nothing beyond what my answer also does? Nothing has the slightest requirement on the actual representation in Big - you could just flip the words around and it would pass all the test and even have the exact same output: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6521bd8e9355898c

The problem then appears to be that the int128 values are arbitrary now. Yes, they may also roundtrip with your more convoluted code, BUT, the integral values do NOT match up between __int128_t and boost::multiprecision::int128_t: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c9112470a0be699. I'd phrase this as "they are wrong".

From the formula it seems you are conflating pure math with CPU arithmetic. They are not the same. E.g. the cause of difference is you're using / TwoPowerNBits instead of >> 64, which does not get the bits you expect (you kinda know this because it's why you're meddling with if (lo != static_cast<int64_t>(lo)) etc. On the "standard" side, you're using operator % which has different semantics for negative numbers (in fact it was Implementation defined for the longest time). Boost's operator% does not have the same semantics.

If you decide that indeed the correspondence between __int128 and Boost is not important to you (this is confusing to me, since, why don't the values matter if you're going to be doing calculations?), you can use import_bits/export_bits. However it will only be convenient for uint128_t because int128_t stores the sign separately, so it would never pack into 2*64 bits: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9003361d015c8090

hi @sehe, thank you for your interest in my question. You are absolutely correct, I did conflate pure math with CPU arithmetic. Please follow this link for the full math vs implementation clarification https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/issues/644#issuecomment-2498331281
I would like to edit my text on the solution, but I can't figure out how to express math equations anymore. Seems like mathjax doesn't work anymore in stackoverflow.

I don't think Mathjax ever worked on the stackoverflow domain (it does work on other stackexchange domains like https://math.stackexchange.com/).

I see you have very good input there. I don't think we're REALLY trying to solve this. There's almost certainly a dose of XY-problem at play here too. I can basically predict that when we solved X, the Y problem will just appear. It's good to rethink the big picture objective. Something made you think you needed to pack 64bit ints into int128. Which, as you have seen, can be done in various ways with different semantics/trade-offs. Whatever you'll choose I think you will find your real questions. In my mind, there's only one sensible representation and that's the one presented in my answer.

@sehe, thank you for your comments and suggestion. I'm developing an application that primarily utilizes hi-lo representation, with occasional use of full integer representation. While attempting to retrieve the original hi-lo integers from a big int on Windows, I encountered inconsistent results. This led me to investigate further, and although initially perplexed, I'm glad we were able to pinpoint the issue. Your help was invaluable.
However, the discrepancy between __int128 and Boost big-int you discovered is disconcerting. I'll look into that. Maybe there's an issue to report to boost.

@sehe, I think I understand the issue. Both hi and lo are -9223372036854775808 (2^63), causing an int64_t overflow. Multiplying by 2^64 yields 2^127, exceeding the 128-bit signed integer range. The sum 2^127 + 2^63 is undefined in two's complement representation.
On the other hand, boost's multiprecision library uses a sign "bit", allowing it to handle larger values. This explains why boost's can accurately represent the result, while the native 128-bit integer cannot.

JZMaddock's reply to this issue

I came up with:
std::array<int64_t, 2> unpack_int128_t(const boost::multiprecision::int128_t& value)
{
   constexpr auto TwoPowerNBits = boost::multiprecision::int128_t(1) << 64;

   boost::multiprecision::int128_t high, low;

   boost::multiprecision::divide_qr(value, TwoPowerNBits, high, low);

   if (boost::multiprecision::bit_test(value, 63))
   {
      low -= TwoPowerNBits;
      ++high;
   }

   std::array<int64_t, 2> result = { static_cast<int64_t>(high), static_cast<int64_t>(low) };

   assert(boost::multiprecision::int128_t(result[0]) * TwoPowerNBits + result[1] == value);

   return result;
}

Which I hope is a little easier to see what's going on.
It would be nice to avoid divide_qr which is more efficient than
separate / and %, but still horribly inefficient compared to
bit-fiddling, but I don't see a good bit-fiddling solution at present!


It failed with
hilo = { -6731861333566513236, 3896236645521988 }
